# Arraylist to array copy Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

```
 ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> L1=new ArrayList<>();
 ArrayList<Integer> L2 = new ArrayList<>();
 ArrayList<Integer> L3 = new ArrayList<>();
 ArrayList<Integer> L4 = new ArrayList<>();
 L2.add(5); L3.add(6); L4.add(9);
 L2.add(2); L3.add(1); L4.add(3);
 L2.add(1); L3.add(1); L4.add(2);
 L1.add(L2); L1.add(L3); L1.add(L4);
 L1.remove(L1.size() - 1);
```

Now I want to save the element removed from L1 in an array. As this list contains three elements, I want to create an array like `int ar[] = new int[3];` and save this removed value into this array.

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: @shmosel Thank you. It already solved.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're ok with `Integer[]` array, then just use `toArray` method:

```
ArrayList<Integer> removed = L1.remove(L1.size() - 1);
Integer[] integers = removed.toArray(new Integer[removed.size()]);
```

If you want `int[]` array, you could use streams:

```
int[] ints = L1.remove(L1.size() - 1).stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
```

`.mapToInt(i -> i)` is used to unbox `Integer` values to `int`

Comment: It's solve my purpose. Let's see what happened with my actual program.